# Python ZIP function removing too many items from file

Tags: python, list, zip

I am reading content from a text file and storing that in a list (each line as a single element)(prizeList). I'm doing the same for winnerList which ia another list.

Im using a zip function to call the emailUser function every time both a winner and an email exist at the same index. The loop will stop if at least one element does not exist at that index.

After the function  is called, remove that prize from the list, remove all content from the file and then write the list content back to the text file (essentially removing that one element).

The issue is that either the line `prizeList.remove(prize)` or `writeTo.write(prizes)` is deleting too much content from the text file. Insted of deleting one element (from txt file) per iteration in the loop it is deleting many more.

Here is my attempt:

```
   for prize, winner in zip(prizeList, emailList):


    print(f'{prize} goes to {winner}')


    emailUserWithPrize(winner, prize, prizeType)

    print("Before: ")
    print(prizeList)

    prizeList.remove(prize)

    file.close()

    writeTo = open(prizeFile, "w")

    prizes = ""
    for i in range(len(prizeList)):
        prizes = prizeList[i]

    writeTo.write(prizes)



    print("After:")
    print(prizeList)

if len(prizeList) < 1:
    print("No more prizes for " + prizeType)
```

Comment: What are the lengths of `prizeList` and `emailList`? If they're of different lengths, then zip uses the first `min([len(prizeList), len(emailList)])` items for the pairing. Could that be it?

Comment: The lengths change depending on how many lines are in the text file, one line is one list element. The chances are they will always be of different lengths. I'm not sure if its deleting double in the zip or if I'm closing the txt file and writing to it again in he wrong place

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're probably inadvertently truncating one of your lists (either `prizeList` or `emailList`), because `zip` only iterates until one of the input lists (more generaly iterators) is finished, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).
You can check that by printing the lengths of each list of course, but I'd guess that's the source of your problems.
*Solving* the problem, depends on what you're actually trying to do, and I can't guess enough base on your code.
Good luck!

---

Update due to a comment: If you're worried you aren't reading and/or writing the text files properly, that's a different issue, and should be checked and debugged as a separate effort.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to deconstruct your code.
You find matches within first items in prize list and email list, right? Then you remove each given prize from prize list. Then if you have any prizes left, you add it to prizes file.

```
prize_list = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']
email_list = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4']

matches = list(zip(prize_list, email_list))

for prize, winner in matches:
    print(f'{prize} goes to {winner}')
    print("Before: ", prize_list)
    print('removing', prize)
    prize_list.remove(prize)
    print('{} prizes left'.format(len(prize_list)))

prize_file = 'prizeFile.txt'
with open(prize_file, "w") as file_:
    for prize in prize_list:
        file_.write(prize)
        file_.write('\n')
```

Output:

```
p1 goes to e1
Before:  ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']
removing p1
5 prizes left
p2 goes to e2
Before:  ['p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']
removing p2
4 prizes left
p3 goes to e3
Before:  ['p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']
removing p3
3 prizes left
p4 goes to e4
Before:  ['p4', 'p5', 'p6']
removing p4
2 prizes left
After: ['p5', 'p6']
```